# My app shuts down and says "unfortunately <appname> has stopped working" I'm very new to programming . Help much appreaciated

Tags: android

THIS IS MY LOGCAT

```
09-18 17:19:50.770: D/AndroidRuntime(797): Shutting down VM
09-18 17:19:50.770: W/dalvikvm(797): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-18 17:19:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(797): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 17:19:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(797): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboston.honey/com.thenewboston.honey.StartingPoint}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Not sure if posting a code snippet would be helpful in debugging.

Comment: post the relevant code and indicate what is line 26 `StartingPoint.java`

Comment: line 26 of StartingPoint is null

Answer (score 1):

Check out line 26 of your onCreate method in StartingPoint.java.

You are experiencing a NullPointerException rooted from whatever is on that line.

As other comments have suggested, a more detailed answer would require your code (specially the contents surrounding line 26)

Comment: This really should be a comment.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with you. While the poster didn't ask too great of a question compared to the normal SO standards, he's asking for help. None of us can solve exactly what is causing the above error and provide a direct, step by step solution in the current context, but we can provide another stepping stone closer to solving his problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer  without code but since you are new it is very important for you to know how to read the logcat when you have a crash. This will allow you to debug the simpler problems yourself and will save on a few headaches occasionally.

First part is to find the line which says `Fatal Exception` like here

```
09-18 17:19:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(797): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

then look for `Caused by:`

```
09-18 17:19:50.800: E/AndroidRuntime(797): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this tells us that the root cause was a `NPE` (NullPointerException). Now look for the next line after that which references your project and that will give you the `Activity`, function, and line number. Here it happens to be the next line

```
at com.thenewboston.honey.StartingPoint.onCreate(StartingPoint.java:26)
```

this tells us that it is happening in `StartingPoint.java` in the `onCreate()`at line 26. So you know to check that line, maybe set a breakpoint and see what is `null` then from there you can figure out *why* it is `null`. And when you can't figure out why then you can post the logcat and most relevant code here. In this sitaion it would be the `onCreate()` method of that `Activity`.

Reading the logcat isn't always this simple but many times it will be.